# Custom background color for UINavigationBar using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to use my own background color for UINavigationBar using SwiftUI but I'm not able to change it using the following code:

```
let attrs = [
     NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
     NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "AbrilFatface-Regular", size: 24)!]

UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attrs
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red:253/255, green:213/255, blue:211/255, alpha:1.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has nothing to do with SwiftUI. For changing UINavigationBar Appearance you must use UIKit which is predecessor of SwiftUI. The code bellow will change Navigation Bars globally.

```swift
// Instantiate new UINavigationBarAppearance object
let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
// Set background colour
navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .black
// Set text color for title
navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
// Set text color for large title
navigationBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

// Assign appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
```

> Call this in **AppDelegate.swift** file indside **application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)** method. This code works for **iOS 13+**.

Here is the apple documentation for [Legacy Customizations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/legacy_customizations) in case you need it.

Comment: Please accept this answer so we know this is the solution. You can accept it with checkmark next to my question

Comment: thank you! that worked perfect. Do you know how we could change individual views after confining this ?